# I can't seem to figure out this nested loop pattern C++

Tags: c++

```
//DrawTriangle("VOTE", true)
E
TE
OTE
VOTE
```

I figured out:

```
//DrawTriangle("VOTE", false)
VOTE
OTE
TE
E
```

Here's what I got so far:

```
            cout << "Please enter your WORD: ";
            cin >> word;
            cout << endl;

            int wordLength = word.length();

            //UP TRI WORD
            if (trDirection == 1)
            {
                //UP TRI TO DO
            }

            //DOWN TRI WORD 
            else if (trDirection == 2)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row <= wordLength; row++)
                {
                    for (int i = row; i < wordLength; i++)
                    {
                        cout << word[i];
                    }
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to invert the sequence - so just invert the outer loop:

```
for (int row = wordLength; row >= 0; row--)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm really not sure why I couldn't think of that.